# Borland C++ 5.02 cout not showing on the console window

Tags: c++, console-application, borland-c++

I'm sorry for this newbie question,
i tried to make this program using borland 5.02, but for some reason the cout in the if (stat) isn't showing on the console window when i write married. I don't know what's wrong and i've been stuck for hours. please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
   int NIP, GOL, GP, TI, TA, JA, TG ;
   char NM[20], STAT[10] ;

   cout << "ID Number : " ;
   cin >> NIP ;

   cout << "Name : " ;
   cin >> NM ;

   cout << "Faction : " ;
   cin >> GOL ;

   if (GOL == 1)
   {
    GP = 1500000 ;
   }
   else if (GOL == 2)
   {
    GP = 2000000 ;
   }
   else
   {
    GP = 2500000 ;
   }

   cout << "Status  : " ;
   gets (STAT) ;

   if (STAT == "Married" || STAT == "married")
   {
      cout << "Number of children : " << endl ;
      cin >> JA ;
      TI = 0.05 * GP ;

      if (JA <= 3)
      {
        TA = 0.02 * GP * JA ;
      }
      else
      {
        TA = 0.02 * GP * 3 ;
      }
   }
   else
   {
    TI = 0 ;
    TA = 0 ;
   }

   TG = GP + TI+ TA ;

   cout << endl << "-Results-" << endl ;
   cout << "Your GP: " << GP << endl ;
   cout << "Your TI: " << TI << endl ;
   cout << "Your TA: " << TA << endl ;
   cout << "Your TG: " << TG << endl ;

   getch () ;

}
```

Update : i have tried to change the `gets(STAT) ;` to `cin >> STAT ;` before but it doesn't seem to have any effect. the program looked like this when i run them

---

ID Number : 0123141421

Name : Vykmon

Faction : 1

Status : married **(Here is the problem)**

-Results-

Your GP: 1500000

Your TI: 0

Your TA: 0

Your TG: 1500000

---

Even though i have write married on the status, the `cout << "Number of children : " << endl ;` didn't show up on console window. it as if the `if (STAT == "Married" || STAT == "married")` aren't working, and the "Status: married" count as

```
else
   {
    TI = 0 ;
    TA = 0 ;
   }
```

Comment: `STAT == "Married"` It's not the way to compare 2 char array

Comment: (`gets()` is deprecated for not providing means to prevent buffer overflow. CAPS names for local variables are - unusual.) What did you try to find out what happens? Make friends with a debugger. `cout << '|' << STAT << '|' << endl;` immediately after `std::cin.get(STAT, sizeof STAT);`. Try `"Married" == STAT` and `"Married" == string(STAT)`.

Comment: Fixed that `main` declaration: C++ has never had "implicit int".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STAT == "Married"` would work in standard C++ if `STAT` were a `std::string`.

However, it's an array of `char`, and that means that you're comparing two *pointers*. Because C++ doesn't support direct comparison of arrays. So each of the two array expressions decay to pointer to first item.

And these pointers are guaranteed to be different.

---

Note 1: Borland C++ 5.02 sounds like mid 1990's, before the first C++ standard. There are a host of free modern compilers. The three most well known are g++, clang and Visual C++ (the latter is only available for the PC platform).

Note 2: As I recall the `std::string` in Borland C++ was totally botched. If just using `std::string` doesn't work, consider using `strcmp` to compare C strings (like the arrays you have).

Note 3: In standard C++ (since the first standard in 1998) there is no `<iostream.h>` header. Instead include `<iostream>`, and possibly add a `using namespace std;`. Or appropriate `using` directives, or qualifications of names like `cout` and `endl`, i.e. writing `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

---

In other news:

- By reserving SHOUTCASE names for macros, you can ease the code reading experience significantly, and avoid unintended text substitutions to boot. Not to mention conforming to the common convention about this.
- By using `getline` instead of `>>`, the program can read a name with a space in it. However, this only works nicely when the input buffer is empty (since `getline` doesn't skip whitespace). So, it's something to consider, but it can involve some work.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to write the code differently, and somehow it's working. But i still didn't know the source of problem from the previous code though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

main()
{
    char NM [20], STAT ;
    int NIP, GOL, GP, JA, TI, TA, TG ;

    cout << "ID Number: " ;
    cin >> NIP ;

    cout << "Name: " ;
    gets (NM) ;

    cout << "Faction: " ;
    cin >> GOL ;

    if (GOL == 1)
        GP = 1500000 ;
    else if (GOL == 2)
        GP = 2000000 ;
    else
        GP = 2500000 ;

    cout << "Status: " ;
    cin >> STAT ;

    if (STAT == 'K')
    {
        TI = 0.05 * GP ;
        cout << "Number of children: " ;
        cin >> JA ;
        if (JA <= 3)
            TA = 0.02 * GP * JA ;
        else
            TA = 0.02 * GP * 3 ;
    }
    else
        TI = 0, TA = 0 ;

    TG = GP + TI + TA ;

    cout << endl << "-Results-" << endl ;
    cout << "Your GP: " << GP << endl ;
    cout << "Your TI: " << TI << endl ;
    cout << "Your TA: " << TA << endl ;
    cout << "Your TG: " << TG << endl ;

    getch () ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've revised your code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
   int NIP, GOL, GP, TI, TA, JA, TG ;
   char NM[20];
   string STAT; // FIX 1 --------------------------------------------------------

   cout << "ID Number : " ;
   cin >> NIP ;

   cout << "Name : " ;
   gets(NM);

   cout << "Faction : " ;
   cin >> GOL ;

   if (GOL == 1)
   {
    GP = 1500000 ;
   }
   else if (GOL == 2)
   {
    GP = 2000000 ;
   }
   else
   {
    GP = 2500000 ;
   }

   cout << "Status  : " ;
   cin>>STAT;

   if ((STAT == "Married") || (STAT == "married"))
    {
      cout << "Number of children : " ; // FIX #2 -------------------------------------------------
      cin >> JA ;
      TI = 0.05 * GP ;

      if (JA <= 3)
      {
        TA = 0.02 * GP * JA ;
      }
      else
      {
        TA = 0.02 * GP * 3 ;
      }
   }
   else
   {
    TI = 0 ;
    TA = 0 ;
   }

   TG = GP + TI+ TA ;

   cout << endl << "-Results-" << endl ;
   cout << "Your GP: " << GP << endl ;
   cout << "Your TI: " << TI << endl ;
   cout << "Your TA: " << TA << endl ;
   cout << "Your TG: " << TG << endl ;

   getch () ;

}
```

The problem was you can't just compare array using if statement in C++
You could've used char, and then just use a single character like 'M'
Or you could instead use string, but maybe it'll cause some warnings.